# next best/worst case for any algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Encountered a question like this for mergesort specifically and was wondering how does one approach a question like this for other algorithms (insertionsort,heapsort,quicksort and etc)

<strike>Is it safe to assume that the **n**th best/worst arrangement for any algorithm is the **n**th step of solving the best/worst arrangement for the same set of data?</strike>

Example:
If the worst case for mergesort with the following array of integers [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] is [1,5,3,7,2,6,4,8]. What is the next worst case for this array of integers?

I assumed it would be the next arrangement when solving the worst case which is [1,3,5,7,2,6,4,8]. Am I approaching such a question wrongly?

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. What is the context?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I added an example question if that helps with understanding my problem.

Comment: There are `n!` cases but only `n log n` steps.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a "next-best" or "next-worst" case is not really well-defined in the first place. Neither is the concept of "the state of the array after one step", because not all algorithms modify an array [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).

---

When we say the "worst case" of an algorithm, we don't mean a single input to an algorithm. For example, the array `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` is *not* - by itself - the worst case of the insertion sort algorithm. This array is one of the worst inputs (i.e. highest number of steps to compute) for insertion sort *out of arrays of length 5*, but we are very rarely interested in arrays of one specific length.

What we mean by "best case" or "worst case" is actually an *infinite family* of inputs, such that each member of that family is a best or worst input *for its own value of n*, and the family must contain inputs for arbitrarily large values of n. So, for example:

- The infinite set of arrays `{[1], [2, 1], [3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2, 1], ...}` is a worst case for insertion sort. For inputs from this infinite set, the asymptotic complexity of insertion sort is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).
- The infinite set of arrays `{[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], ...}` is a best case for insertion sort. For inputs from this infinite set, the asymptotic complexity of insertion sort is Θ(n).

Note that the (larger) infinite set of all arrays which are in descending order is also a worst case for insertion sort, and the (larger) infinite set of all arrays in ascending order is also a best case. So the family is not unique, but the asymptotic complexity of the algorithm on inputs from any two "best case" (or any two "worst case") families is the same.

---

Now we've got that out of the way, let's think about what a "next-best" or "next-worst" case would have to mean. If the asymptotic complexity of insertion sort on some family of inputs is also Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), then that family *is* a worst case for insertion sort; so the asymptotic complexity of a "next-worst" case would have to be something lower than Θ(n<sup>2</sup>).

But however small a gap you choose, it is not the "next-worst":

- If you choose a family where the complexity is Θ(n<sup>1.999</sup>), then it is not "next-worst" because I can find another family where the complexity is  Θ(n<sup>1.9999</sup>).
- If you choose a family where the complexity is Θ(n<sup>2</sup> / log n), I can find one where it's Θ(n<sup>2</sup> / log log n).

That is, the asymptotic complexities of different families of possible inputs for insertion sort form a [dense order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order), for any two different complexities there is another complexity in between those two, so there is no "next" or "previous" one.